# Can't call functions from Vfw.h inside Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, unreal-engine4, .lib

Sorry in advance if this question is too specific to Unreal Engine, but after 6 months of working, this is the last piece that I need to complete, and I have become desperate.

After creating an Unreal Engine C++ base project, added some .h and .cpp files with VS class wizard, I can't use functions like `AVIFileInit` and other similar ones, even though I have included Vfw.h and put it inside AllowWindowsPlatformTypes.h and HideWindowsPlatformTypes.h. All I get is error `LNK2019: unresolved external symbol AVIFileInit referenced`. What I want to do is experiment in Unreal Engine based on the article [Various methods for capturing the screen](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen?fid=23443&fr=76#xx0xx).

I have tried to put all the code into a separate VS project and building it as a static library, and then linking it to the Unreal Engine project. All is fine, but when I try to build the project, it generates a list of LNK2001 errors, all of which involve functions like `AVIFileInit`, `AVIFileExit`, ...

Note: I am using version 4.6.1

Any help and tip would be much appreciated.

Comment: Following this instruction [link](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Linking_Static_Libraries_Using_The_Build_System), i manage to use functions from vfw library and other. Thank you all very much, thank you zenzelezz for talking care of all those grammar error and sorry for all those grammar error.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Vfw32.lib` to your project from *Project Properties* -> *Linker* -> *Input* -> *Additional Dependencies*.